# Problems with embedding youtube with xslt transforms

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have multiple video links from youtube stored in an xml file, I have added code that will allow these to be embedded, xml element is video. Each element is stored in an outer element with an id, and only sections with each id are only visible one at a time. 
The pblem is that only 1 section has all of its videos embedded while others will either have none or will have the other sections videos. Code is shown below

```
<xsl:for-each select="item/items[@id='id1']">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Video</th>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <iframe width="512" 
                        height="308" 
                        src="{video}" 
                        frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there another way to get this to work?

EDIT - Below is a sample xml file in the format of what I am transforming.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="items.xsl"?>
<item>
<items id="id1">
<video>http://www.youtube.com/embed/0iCFi14Glbk</video>
</items>
<items id="id1">
<video>http://www.youtube.com/embed/rMCh4etBbkU</video>
</items>
```

These embedded videos should be displayed in a table as shown in the xsl above.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3480061/How-To-Add-a-YouTube-Video-to-Your-Web-Site.htm

The link above shows the way in which i want this to work with the embeded video displayed

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML you are transforming?

Comment: I don't understand the explanation. You should better post the input sample and the desired output.

Comment: @Alejandro  @Fishcake: added example for referance

Comment: For that input sample, what is your desired output? Please, explicity provide one.

Comment: @Alejandro: added a link that shows how i want to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the code something was wrong with youtube